# R plot - spurious lines appear when exported in pdf format

Tags: r, pdf, plot

Following [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774928/removing-part-of-a-graphic-in-r/16777379#16777379) (this one is independent of the previous one, though), I ended up with the following nice (isn't it?!) picture (R code is shown below).

However, when I export the picture in pdf format, the quality is kind of disappointing; spurious white lines appear in the top right corner :(

Do you have a solution?

[image]

---

```
library(gplots)

f <- function(S1, S2, theta)
{
  num <- (S1^(-theta) + S2^(-theta) - 1)^(-1 / theta)
  denom <- S1 * S2
  return(num / denom)
}

S1 <- S2 <- seq(0.05, 0.95, 0.01)
z <- outer(S1, S2, FUN=f, theta=2/3)
levels=seq(1.1, 8, length.out=25)

windows(5,5)
par(mgp=c(2, 0.5, 0))
plot(NA,
     xlim=rev(c(0, 1)), xlab=expression(S[1](t)), xaxt="n",
     ylim=rev(c(0, 1)), ylab="", yaxt="n",
     frame=FALSE)
mtext(text=bquote(S[2](t)), side=2, line=1.8, las=1) 
axis(1, c(1, 0), label=TRUE, tcl=-0.5)
axis(1, seq(1, 0, -0.25), label=FALSE, tcl=-0.25)
axis(2, c(1, 0), label=TRUE, tcl=-0.5)
axis(2, seq(1, 0, -0.25), label=FALSE, tcl=-0.25)
par(mgp=c(3, 1, 0))  

.filled.contour(x=S1, y=S2, z=z,
                levels=levels,
                col=colorpanel(length(levels), "gray95", "gray20", "black"))
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628463/pdf-of-figure-in-r-has-unsightly-white-lines-in-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `pdf()` function directly rather than using `windows()` first and then exporting.

If that doesn't work, it may be due to your pdf viewer. See the [R FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-are-there-unwanted-borders) on why there are unwanted borders, lines or grid-like artifacts when viewing a plot saved to a PS or PDF file.

Comment: #JeanVAdams: It does not change. Does it for you?

Comment: It may be due to your pdf viewer.  See the [R FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-are-there-unwanted-borders) on why there are _unwanted borders, lines or grid-like artifacts when viewing a plot saved to a PS or PDF file?_

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll try the proposed solutions soon.

Comment: Disabling line art smoothing in Acrobat Reader works :)
Thank you! If you edit your answer with the link in it, I will accept it.